# EF Core Select query with null references

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have a `Select` query that performs a check on a child navigation property to then check another referenced property. The first child navigation property can be null but the second property `isRequired()` and if the first child is not null in the database, the query runs fine but if one or more rows exist that do not have a referencing value for that property then I get -

> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query
> for...

How can I make a query with an optional property run and return null for the records that have no references.

```cs
await _dbContext.NewsBoard
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(item => new NewsResponse
    {
        Id = item.BoardId,
        MediaType = new MediaTypeResponse 
        { 
             Id = item.Media.MediaTypeId, 
             Name = item.Media.MediaType.Name 
        },
```

Above is the query I am trying to run, the `item.Media` does not exist have a value for its foreign key (its null) and so the expected result would have been a list of `NewsResponse` with MediaType being null where there is a null referenced `item.Media`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `null` check in your query like -

```
await _dbContext.NewsBoard
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Select(item => new NewsResponse
        {
            Id = item.BoardId,
            MediaType = item.Media == null ? null : new MediaTypeResponse  // null check
            {
                Id = item.Media.MediaTypeId,
                Name = item.Media.MediaType.Name
            }
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Wow I totally over looked this, I didn't now EF Core would accept ternary like this. Thanks for the tip